# Cube.js: invalid token

Tags: cube.js

In the server of cubejs, I generated a token by `cubejs token -e "180 day"`.

Then I assign it to `CUBEJS_API_SECRET` in `.env`; and assign it to `const cubejsApi = cubejs(...`. Then I launched the backend and the frontend, I got the following error:

```
Invalid Token: {
  "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE1ODg5MzQyOTYsImV4cCI6MTYwNDQ4NjI5Nn0.RVdHlpfubXDgwG1FRYbUm-UDLVBjnb-HSVTK5bEy-ZU"
} 
JsonWebTokenError: invalid signature
    at /Users/chengtie/Downloads/tmp20200414/cubejs/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:133:19
    at getSecret (/Users/chengtie/Downloads/tmp20200414/cubejs/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:90:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as verify] (/Users/chengtie/Downloads/tmp20200414/cubejs/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:94:10)
    at ApiGateway.defaultCheckAuth (/Users/chengtie/Downloads/tmp20200414/cubejs/node_modules/@cubejs-backend/api-gateway/index.js:551:28)
    at ApiGateway.checkAuth (/Users/chengtie/Downloads/tmp20200414/cubejs/node_modules/@cubejs-backend/api-gateway/index.js:572:18)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/chengtie/Downloads/tmp20200414/cubejs/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/chengtie/Downloads/tmp20200414/cubejs/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/chengtie/Downloads/tmp20200414/cubejs/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/chengtie/Downloads/tmp20200414/cubejs/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/chengtie/Downloads/tmp20200414/cubejs/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
```

Regardless of this error, it seems that the data query worked. Does anyone know what happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CUBEJS_API_SECRET` is generated by default when Cube.js project is created. Unless you want to redefine it you don't need to assign it in `.env` file. You should only pass it to `cubejs()` on client side. Please see https://cube.dev/docs/security#generating-token.